Do you need attitude control on a small CubeSat?
It's my first time designing a CubeSat. I'm making a 1U. I'm wondering if I need to make a sat with any sort of attitude control or can I just let it float around in space? And do I need any wings or stabilizers, or can it really just be a cube?
Will I need thrust or attitude control to stay in orbit? I'm planning to launch in the normal LEO zone.

There is no answer for this.  Whether you need attitude control or to stay in orbit depends entirely on the mission of the CubeSat you're designing.

Would suggest specifically control hinges on what your cubsat does - if a sensor or antenna only works facing earth then you need to do something to achieve that. Suggest having a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacecraft_attitude_control#Passive_attitude_control and possible revisiting this question

@uhoh let's move this out of this user's inbox and into a chat room

Hi Charles - welcome. You'll see from the comments, your question needs a fair bit more info to be able to give a specific answer. If you can edit in details regarding your project and what you need it and the sensors on board to do, we should be able to reopen this question for further answers.

I would edit myself, but obviously I have no clue about what OP actually wants to do. Also, speaking from just logic, I'd say that anything with a solar panel might (probably?) need(s) attitude control to charge and avoid overheating, unless, of course, you've solar panels on all sides. As @RoryAlsop mentioned, it depends on the details, such as its goal and sensors, equipment, etc.


Do you need attitude control on a small CubeSat?

No, not for a minimal cubesat that doesn't require orientation.
But, the payload might require a cubesat that does have one!

A 1U cubesat could have at east some some photovoltaic cells on all six sides, and antenna configurations can be made isotropic (e.g. crossed-dipoles fed 90° out of phase - (e.g. a "turnstile" antenna) would be the simplest way. (those need a ground receiver that can handle continuous drifting between all kinds of elliptical polarization states.)

What is Canted Turnstile Antenna System? What it its Applications?
How can a crossed dipole (turnstile) antenna be omnidirectional in 3D?

The cubesat might have an unusual purpose- recording GPS signals, or FM radio signals from Earth, or have simple photodiodes on all six sides that record the ratio of 60 Hz to 50 Hz to DC light from the Earth at night, or low frequency signals from the ionosphere... or it could have an internal microgravity experiment payload and internal sensors or camera, or it could have bright, blinking LEDs on all six sides to be (barely) noticeable on the ground, or the cremated remains of somebody's pet...

Radio Pollution Payload for CubeSat

Now you might worry if it spun to fast for some reason - there are passive systems that can deploy that would very slowly damp rotation using shorted copper coils and the Earth's magnetic field (Eddy current damping) or drag-induced damping. These might slow excess rotation without controlling attitude per se if you have an issue with rotation.
But basically, no, they don't.
But if some part of the cubesat's payload needs orientation control - precise or not, then that payload would require some cubesat that does have attitude control.


And do I need any wings or stabilizers, or can it really just be a cube?

Yep, it can be a cube.
While a few cubesats do use drag from the very very thin atmosphere on their solar panels to make very small orbital adjustments those are special cubesats flying in formation. For a one-off cubesat, you don't need those either.

Will I need thrust or attitude control to stay in orbit?

Also no.
See for example answers to Do all artificial satellites have engines?
We covered the attitude control already. The only other reason to use thrust would be to "stay in orbit". Most amateur cubesat missions are pretty short, a few months to a year - they slowly lose altitude and eventually reenter the atmosphere. This is important because they often stop working and become useless space junk, and some of them never even start working.
So it is greatly encouraged for for amateur cubesats to just slowly lose altitude and reenter.
